# For Android Second Screen using Presentation How do use action listeners defined in activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a current app for which I have a layout file with a button and text box.

Now I would like the app to support a second display using the Presentation class provided by Android. I wish to use a different layout file for the same to change size and position for my text and button view.

The problem in hand is that all my action listeners like onclick, ontouch are currently defined in my Activity class. Is there a way in which I can reuse the code in my presentation object also.

Comment: Well, since nobody can click on the presentation, I'm not sure what you're aiming at. I am not aware that Android supports external touchscreen-enabled monitors, and very few users would have such things today. The second display is for display only.

Comment: Although it sounds better in theory I was planning to connect as a socket client to socket server running at the presentation screen which will send me x y coordinates of the touch made by the user in the external display. Then using dispatch events I was thinking of emulating a click

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for the answer till Android O you have to write separate action listeners. There is no way via which the same action listeners can be used. I was able to do this by auto generating the Java code from the Activity code and then using MotionEvent to generate the touch.